# "service" command on virtualbox service fails silently

Tags: server, virtualbox, services, genymotion

I want to run genymotion on my ubuntu, but it fails. It seems that virtualbox service is not running properly. But when I run `service virtaulbox status` it does not response and finishes silently.
If i run `service virtualbox start` the result is the same.
What is the problem and how it should be solved?

**UPDATE:** `service --status-all` results in

```
[ ? ] vboxautostart-service
[ - ] virtualbox
```

Any one could help?

Comment: Probably Secure Boot. Try disabling it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks, but how to disable Secure Boot?

Comment: It's a UEFI feature so... UEFI settings. And if you don't know yet, UEFI is what replaced BIOS a long time ago.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia But my laptop has BIOS, not UEFI and I am ising ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If it really has BIOS - it must be very old - then it certainly isn't Secure Boot. And 14.04 is out of support and off-topic here. Please upgrade to a supported release.